# Does Karaf support downloading of transitive dependencies from maven central?

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I am trying to use Karaf and I was wondering if it is possible to configure it to pull the transitive dependencies from the Apache Maven Central repository.  Without having to use "embedded bundles"

I already know you can pull explicit dependencies, the key part of the the question is the "transitive" ones.

I also know you can use OBR to read from a repository.xml file in a deployed site, but I can't find one for Maven central.  A possible answer to the question would be to add the URL, but I can't find it documented anywhere what the repository.xml URL is.

At the moment, my work around is to figure out what the dependencies are and explicitly add them to the

Embedded bundles do not work with the Karaf OSGi blueprint implementation (it just waits for something that won't exist).  I also find it ugly to have to do that.  Another possible answer I can think of for this question is if there were instructions to create a package that can be deployed to *any* OSGi container (not just Karaf using KAR files) that contains all the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way of doing this in a relatively OSGi standard way using Maven.  It uses the maven-dependency-plugin to create a repository that only contains the dependencies that is required on the runtime scope.

Then the maven-bundle-plugin:index goal is executed to create the repository.xml file.

At this point in the target you have a valid obr repository, the maven-assembly-plugin can be used to package it up as needed.

The following pom.xml snippet will do what is required.

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-runtime-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <copyPom>true</copyPom>
                        <useRepositoryLayout>true</useRepositoryLayout>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>index</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>index</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <mavenRepository>${project.build.directory}/dependency</mavenRepository>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

As for Karaf, this a bundle along with its transitive dependencies can be installed without using Karaf's feature.xml using the following commands:

```
features:install obr
obr:addUrl [location of the OBR repository, can be file:///....]
obr:deploy [symbolicname-of-bundle]
start [symbolicname-of-bundle]
```

And voila.

Note that this will only load up the bundles that are referenced by the bundle you had specified so if you're using something like Blueprint where in theory it shouldn't know about the other bundles, then you have to explicitly deploy them or create an uber bundle that will contain the bundles you have (like a feature/product)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the karaf-maven-plugin to create a feature file from maven dependencies. This will resolve transitive dependencies.

Comment: again I ask for an example, when I did this yesterday I just get NullPointerExceptions.  Also my question text explicitly states that I am looking for something that will work in ANY OSGi container not just Karaf

Comment: Can you post your sample project somewhere? I can then take a look at it and check why you get a Nullpointer exception. This could mean that there is a bug somewhere. As far as I know there is no container independent answer to this problem. Please also check that you use the most current version of Karaf. For an example you can look at the karaf source code in assemblies/features. It uses the karaf maven plugin to create its own features.

Comment: actually for container independence I would think OBR would do it, but   I haven't found a way to create an OBR repository with the transitive dependencies, just specific bundles.

Comment: feel free to fork an answer :)

Comment: I have not done much with OBR repos till now but technically they are a better solution than maven of course. Practially I think karaf feature files are easier to use at the moment. About your project above. I have checked it out and build it with maven without any problems. Btw. I have not seen a reference to the karaf-maven-plugin to create a feature there anywhere. (I used the "emerging-technologies" branch.

Comment: I took it out.  I couldn't get it working so I didn't commit the changes.

Comment: Please add it again so I can debug the case. You can use a different branch if you want to separate it.

Comment: I actually found the problem with using the features plugin.  It seems to be because of the        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>       <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
dependency that causes a null pointer exception.  Unfortunately if I don't use that (i.e. use javax.javaee-api) then my maven-Checkstyle-plugin report will have errors.

Comment: Can you create a small test project that shows this and create an issue for Karaf? A Nullpointer exception is tpyically something that should not happen and should be fixed in the karaf tools.

Comment: I found the reason now.  Or at least a fix for it

Comment: <configuration>
       <!-- This configuration is needed otherwise Karaf Features plugin 
        will throw a NullPointer exception because it tries to scan the dependencies 
        which may have invalid manifests like the org.jboss.spec -->
       <kernelVersion>2.2.8</kernelVersion>
      </configuration>

Comment: However, now it does not do the transitive dependencies for updated versions of Spring.  So what ends up happening is to use the Features plugin, we need to lower the versions to the ones that are provided by Karaf.

Comment: or in my case I just had to add them explicitly to the pom.xml

Comment: The OBR approach works great at runtime (100% OSGi), but I can't get it running with PaxExam.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the best you can do is use Maven to download all the dependancies, and then use the [Felix bnd plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) to convert your local (or remote) repository into an OBR that you can use with Karaf.

Comment: Any example of how to do this conversion?

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano The link I provided goes into some examples. It's basically a matter or setting up the pom file with some additional details (again, see the link), and then running `mvn clean install` or `mvn clean deploy`

Comment: I did see the link earlier on and the examples only show how to install the bundle for the pom in question, it does not show you how to include the transitive dependencies.

Comment: hence why I am asking for an example.